# Is there a way to attach to a transaction in mysql?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have some python code that does several inserts/updates/deletes to mysql.  For debugging, I wish to set the breakpoints at several places and examine the database from the command line.

However, I can't, since the program does its activity in a transaction.

Is there a way to attach to a transaction in mysql just as I can attach to a process using a debugger?

thanks.

Comment: Why not disable the transaction for debugging?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.  This is a great idea.  I am using a company-brewed database connection layer, so I don't know if I can, but I'll go search for it.  Is there a way to do disable it server wide?  I'm running unittests, so I don't mind turning it off temporarily.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know  how to disable it server wide (except of turning all tables to MyISAM (-; ). I would disable it in the code i'm debugging.

Comment: If you use a framework, you might try to write a temprary listener which will execute `COMMIT` after every executed SQL query.